# No actualizar campos en la base de datos si se envían datos vacíos

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql

Mi pregunta es como hacerle para que si no se le da valor a los input file no se actualicen esos campos ya que me los cambia en la base de datos por nada deja el campo en blanco

Aqui es donde Se reciben los datos por el metodo POST

```
    $nombre = $_FILES['archivo1']['name'];
move_uploaded_file($_FILES['archivo1']['tmp_name'],"../scans/".$_FILES['archivo1']['name']);

$nombre2 = $_FILES['archivo2']['name'];
move_uploaded_file($_FILES['archivo2']['tmp_name'],"../scans/".$_FILES['archivo2']['name']);

$nombre3 = $_FILES['archivo3']['name'];
move_uploaded_file($_FILES['archivo3']['tmp_name'],"../scans/".$_FILES['archivo3']['name']);


$id=$_POST['idaps'];
$a=$_POST['rancho'];
$b=$_POST['ciclo'];
$c=$_POST['selectchar'];
$d=$_POST['desinfinst'];
$e=$_POST['desinfcharol'];
$f=$nombre;
$g=$_POST['comentarios1'];
$h=$_POST['fermentacionmic'];
$i=$nombre2;
$j=$_POST['comentarios2'];
$k='Listo';
$l=$nombre3;
$m=$_POST['comentarios3'];
$n=$_POST['respinsp'];
$o=$_POST['resprepor'];

$query="UPDATE actividades_previa_siembra SET id_rancho='$a', id_ciclo='$b', selec_charolas_varied='$c', desinfeccion_inst='$d', desinfeccion_charolas='$e', scan_receta_desinfectante='$f', comentariosd='$g', fermentacion_micorizas='$h', scan_receta_micoriza='$i', comentariosm='$j', preparacion_sustrato='$k', scan_receta_sustrato='$l', comentariosS='$m', id_resp_acti='$n', id_resp_reporte='$o' WHERE id_aps ='$id'";
$resultado=$conexion->query($query);
echo mysql_error();

if ($resultado) {
        header("Location: index.php");
    }else{
        echo "Error";
    }
```

Comment: Puesdes mostrar el codigo que guarda tu modelo.

Comment: Listo espero y sirva

Comment: El código que compartes puede sufrir ataques de inyección SQL. Usar PDO/MySQLi en lugar de `mysql_*` es un primer paso, pero debes usar sentencias preparadas para evitar posibles problemas.

Comment: @J.Doe ¿Tienes una fuente fiable (y preferiblemente oficial) que confirme eso? En [el sitio web de PHP](http://php.net/manual/es/pdo.prepared-statements.php), se recomienda las sentencias preparadas por su utilidad y beneficios y no se menciona nada de que estén obsoletas. Creo que estás confundiendo sentencias preparadas con funciones `mysql_*` (que son un problema de seguridad, obsoletas desde PHP 5.5 y eliminadas en PHP7).

Answer (score 6):

La forma más sencilla para poder hacerlo dinámico sería utilizando los nombres de los campos de la base de datos como nombres del formulario, o hacer un mapping de estos en la lógica de tu aplicación. Por asuntos de simplicidad vamos a usar la primera idea.

Esta solución no está probada como tal, por lo cual pueden haber algunos errores pequeños:

```
$sqlStr = '';

// tomamos los campos (no archivos) del formulario que no están vacios
// los almacenamos en un array, cada uno como un string: campo='valor'
if (!empty($_POST)) {
    foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {
        if (trim($value) != '') {
            $sqlArr[] = "$key='$value'";
        }
}

// tomamos los archivos enviados con el formulario cuyo nombre no está vacio
// almacenamos los nombres en un array, cada uno como un string: campo='nombre-archivo'
if (!empty($_FILES)) {
    foreach ($_FILES as $key => $file) {
        if (trim($file['name']) != '') {
            $sqlArr[] = "$key='$file['name']'";
        }
    }
}

// convertimos el array a string
$sqlStr = implode(", ", $sqlArr);


// si hacemos: echo $sqlStr;
// obtendríamos algo así: campo1='valor1', campo3='valor3', archivo1='nombre1'

// anexamos el string resultante al resto de la consulta
$query = "UPDATE actividades_previa_siembra SET $sqlStr";
```

Comment: Cuidado con la consulta resultado, si no interpreto mal carece de clausula `WHERE id_aps ='$id'` (tal como aparece en el código de la pregunta) que limite los registros afectados, sin la cual actualizaría toda la tabla `actividades_previa_siembra`.

Answer (score 1):

Eso lo tenés que hacer con JavaScript/Jquery antes de enviar tu petición por medio de ajax al php que realiza la consulta con la BD.

Me explico:

Si hay un campo que queda en blanco o no tiene la longitud permitida, la info que se envia por medio de ajax al php que realiza la consulta va a ser una, y sino va a ser otra.

Por ejemplo:

html:

```
<input type="text" placeholder="nombre" id="nombre"/>

<input type="text" placeholder="apellido" id="apellido"/>

<button id="enviar">Enviar</button>
```

jquery:

```
$("#enviar").click(function(){

    var nombre = $.trim($("#nombre").val());

    var apellido = $.trim($("#apellido").val());

    function enviarFormulario(nombre, apellido){
        var datos = {
            "nombre" : nombre,
            "apellido" : apellido
        };

        $.ajax({
            type: "post",
            url: "actualizar.php",
            data: datos,
            success: function(guardados){
                if(guardados){
                    //Informa la respuesta por medio de un cuadro de diálogo
                    //o pon el código que quieras
                }else{
                    //Mensaje de error
                }
            }
        });
    }

    if(nombre.length > 0 && nombre.length <= 10 && apellido.length > 0 && apellido.length <= 10){

        enviarFormulario(nombre, apellido);

    }else if(nombre.length > 0 && nombre.length <= 10 && apellido.length == 0){
        enviarFormulario(nombre, apellido);
    }else if(nombre.length == 0 && apellido.length == 0){
        alert("Debes completar los campos para actualizarlos");
    }//Y puedes agregar todas las excepciones que quieras/necesites
});
```

actualizar.php:

```
<?php

require_once("conexion.php"); //tu archivo de conexión

if(!isset($_SESSION)){
    session_start();
}

$nom = $_POST["nombre"];

$ape= $_POST["apellido"];

$id= $_SESSION["id"];

$actualizado = 0;

$query1 = "SELECT * from usuarios WHERE id = '$id'";

if($resp1 = mysqli_query($conexion, $query1){

    $fila = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resp1);

    $nomDb = $fila["nombre"];

    $apeDb = $fila["apellido"];

    if($nom != "" && $nom != $nomDb){

        $query2 = "UPDATE usuarios SET nombre = '$nom' WHERE id = '$id'";

        if(mysqli_query($conexion, $query2)){
          $actualizado++;
        }else{
          die("Error al actualizar el campo 'nombre'");
        }
    }
    if($ape != "" && $ape != $apeDb){

      $query3 = "UPDATE usuarios SET apellido = '$ape' WHERE id = '$id'";

      if(mysqli_query($conexion, $query3)){
        if($actualizado == 1){
          echo true;
        }else{
          echo "Algun(os) dato(s) no pudo/pudieron ser actualizado(s)";
        }
      }else{
        die("Error al actualizar el campo Apellido");
      }
    }
}else{
  die("error de conexión");
}

mysqli_close($conexion);

?>
```

De esta manera y con este super resumido ejemplo que hice, podrás evitar esos errores que tienes en tu código. Hasta luego.

Answer (score 1):

Si lo que quieres es actualizar el campo del archivo sin actualizar el resto de los campos, deberás verificar cada campo e ir armando el query en función de los campos que si tienen datos.

```
//Algo asi con js
var query = "UPDATE TABLE SET ";
if ( columna1 != "" ){
   query = "col="+columna1; 
}
```

y así.

Answer (score 0):

Tal y como tienes el código, lo mas "fácil", sería que hicieses 4 UPDATES.
Por un lado haces el UPDATE de todos los datos, menos de los FILE, que subes, y por otro lado haces los UPDATE de los FILE, de esta manera, te ahorras también posibles fallos en caso de no tener ficheros que subir.

```
<?php

    $id=$_POST['idaps'];
    $a=$_POST['rancho'];
    $b=$_POST['ciclo'];
    $c=$_POST['selectchar'];
    $d=$_POST['desinfinst'];
    $e=$_POST['desinfcharol'];
    $g=$_POST['comentarios1'];
    $h=$_POST['fermentacionmic'];
    $j=$_POST['comentarios2'];
    $k='Listo';
    $m=$_POST['comentarios3'];
    $n=$_POST['respinsp'];
    $o=$_POST['resprepor'];

    if (!isset($_POST['archivo1'])){
      $nombre = $_FILES['archivo1']['name'];
      move_uploaded_file($_FILES['archivo1']['tmp_name'],"../scans/".$_FILES['archivo1']['name']);
      $query="UPDATE actividades_previa_siembra SET scan_receta_desinfectante='$f' WHERE id_aps ='$id'";
      $resultado=$conexion->query($query);
      echo mysql_error();
    }

    if (!isset($_POST['archivo2'])){
      $nombre2 = $_FILES['archivo2']['name'];
      move_uploaded_file($_FILES['archivo2']['tmp_name'],"../scans/".$_FILES['archivo2']['name']);
      $query="UPDATE actividades_previa_siembra SET scan_receta_micoriza='$i'' WHERE id_aps ='$id'";
      $resultado=$conexion->query($query);
      echo mysql_error();
    }

    if (!isset($_POST['archivo3'])){
      $nombre3 = $_FILES['archivo3']['name'];
      move_uploaded_file($_FILES['archivo3']['tmp_name'],"../scans/".$_FILES['archivo3']['name']);
      $query="UPDATE actividades_previa_siembra SET scan_receta_sustrato='$l' WHERE id_aps ='$id'";
      $resultado=$conexion->query($query);
      echo mysql_error();
    }



    $query="UPDATE actividades_previa_siembra SET id_rancho='$a', id_ciclo='$b', selec_charolas_varied='$c', desinfeccion_inst='$d', desinfeccion_charolas='$e', comentariosd='$g', fermentacion_micorizas='$h',  comentariosm='$j', preparacion_sustrato='$k',  comentariosS='$m', id_resp_acti='$n', id_resp_reporte='$o' WHERE id_aps ='$id'";
    $resultado=$conexion->query($query);
    echo mysql_error();

    if ($resultado) {
          header("Location: index.php");
      }else{
          echo "Error";
      }
    ?>
```

Comment: Yo creo que sería más fácil aún con una función que procese los archivos, para evitar tanta reescritura de código.

Comment: Lo de fácil era solo porque era lo que menos cambio produce en su código.

Comment: Respeto tu punto de vista, pero aún así puede ser menos cambio la función, es lo mismo pero más resumido. Saludos :)

Answer (score 0):

Lo tenés que solucionar a nivel base de datos.

Acá tenés la solución a tu problema. Básicamente le indicas a tu base de datos que valor tiene que tener un campo si no recibe datos.

http://www.comocreartuweb.com/curso-php-y-msql/las-bases-de-datos/crear-la-base-de-datos/predeterminado.html

Comment: Leonardo, es mejor si agregas el código y la explicación que tan solo un enlace.

Answer (score 0):

Puede haber más de un modo de hacerlo.

Yo haría una función para evaluar *$FILES* y si tienen valor, hacer *Update*.

```
function evaluar ( $archivo)
{
  // Operador ternario
  $retorno = empty( $archivo) ? true: false;

  return $retorno;
}
```

Entonces harías algo como lo siguiente:

```
$nombre1 = $_FILES['archivo1']['name'];
$nombre2 = $_FILES['archivo2']['name'];
$nombre3 = $_FILES['archivo3']['name'];

// Si uno devuelve true, está vacío, entonces entra el if
if (evaluar($nombre1) or evaluar($nombre2) or evaluar($nombre3))
{
  exit();
  // O un header, ya lo que quieras hacer.

}

// Si no entra al if significa que las 3 tienen valor, entonces procedes
$id=$_POST['idaps'];
$a=$_POST['rancho'];
$b=$_POST['ciclo'];
// Etc.
```

Sin embargo, para mejor experiencia al usuario, lo ideal es indicarle por *Js* que debe seleccionar una imagen, de lo contrario tiene que esperar a la respuesta del servidor. Aún así por seguridad es mejor validar por lado del cliente y del servidor.